# Spotify Discord Bot - Python

Tags: discord, spotify

The bot joins discord replies with the command /play 'name of a song' gives out 4 options to choose from but then when I reply with the option nothing happens. This is the code:

```
# define a command for playing a song
@qwertybot.command()
async def play(ctx, song):
    # check if the user is in a voice channel
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
        return
    
    # search Spotify for the top 4 options based on the song name
    results = sp.search(q=song, limit=4, type='track')
    options = results['tracks']['items']
    
    # check if any options were found
    if not options:
        await ctx.send("No songs found for that query!")
        return
    
    # send the top 4 options to the user in a numbered list
    message = ""
    for i, option in enumerate(options):
        message += f"{i+1}. {option['name']} - {', '.join([artist['name'] for artist in option['artists']])}\n"
    message += "Reply with the number of the option you want to play."
    await ctx.send(message)
    
    # wait for the user to reply with the option number
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel and msg.content.isdigit() and int(msg.content) in range(1, 5)
    reply = await qwertybot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    option = options[int(reply.content) - 1]
    
    # join the voice channel of the user who issued the command
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(qwertybot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

    if not voice:
        voice = await vc.connect()
    else:
        await voice.move_to(vc)

    # play the selected song
    track_info = sp.track(option['id'])
    preview_url = track_info['preview_url']
    player = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(preview_url))
    voice.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f"Finished playing {option['name']}"))

    # notify the user that the song is playing
    await ctx.send(f"Playing {option['name']} in {vc}")
    
    # wait for the song to finish playing before disconnecting from the voice channel
    while voice.is_playing():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await voice.disconnect()
```

I tried creating a new command prefix to see if it replied, checked the api tokens, the discord bot's permissions maybe a few other things but I cant remember. Anyone has a clue of what might be going on?